# How to pass initial parameter to django's ModelForm instance?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

The particular case I have is like this:

I have a Transaction model, with fields: `from`, `to` (both are `ForeignKey`s to `auth.User` model) and `amount`. In my form, I'd like to present the user 2 fields to fill in: `amount` and `from` (`to` will be automaticly set to current user in a view function).

Default widget to present a `ForeignKey` is a select-box. But what I want to get there, is limit the choices to the `user.peers` queryset members only (so people can only register transactions with their peers and don't get flooded with all system users).

I tried to change the ModelForm to something like this:

```
class AddTransaction(forms.ModelForm):
  from = ModelChoiceField(user.peers)
  amount = forms.CharField(label = 'How much?')

  class Meta:
    model = models.Transaction
```

But it seems I have to pass the queryset of choices for `ModelChoiceField` right here - where I don't have an access to the web `request.user` object.

How can I limit the choices in a form to the user-dependent ones?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the following method (hopefully it's clear enough):

```
class BackupForm(ModelForm):
    """Form for adding and editing backups."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        systemid = kwargs.pop('systemid')
        super(BackupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['units'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                required=False,
                queryset=Unit.objects.filter(system__id=systemid),
                widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'title': _("Add unit")}))

    class Meta:
        model = Backup
        exclude = ('system',)
```

Create forms like this:

```
form_backup = BackupForm(request.POST,
                         instance=Backup,
                         systemid=system.id)
form_backup = BackupForm(initial=form_backup_defaults,
                         systemid=system.id)
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if you need me to explain more in depth.

Comment: From inside the Form class you can access the Model instance through `self.instance`. Remember the instance will be rather blank when Add/Creating a new object.

Comment: Slightly simpler is catching systemid as a regular argument in your __init__() while passing **kwargs straight through: 
        `def __init__(self, systemid, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BackupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Where does this `Backup` and `BackupForm` come from?

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this problem as well, and this was my solution:

```
class ChangeEmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(ChangeEmailForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].initial = user.email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email',)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the user into the `__init__` of the form, and then call `super(…)`. Then set `self.fields['from'].queryset` to `user.peers`