# In Django, how to pass a value into form class

Tags: python, django

Some of my mistakes here are to do with my very limited python knowledge as much as anything, however I have been searching for half a day now.

```py
class AssignmentForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs, m_id):
    super(AssignmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Making name required
    self.fields['title'].required = True
    self.fields['title'].help_text = "Title Required"
    self.fields['description'].required = True
    self.fields['description'].help_text= "Description Optional"
    self.fields['module_id'].required = False
    self.fields['module_id'] = m_id

class Meta:
    # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
    model = Assignment
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'module_id')
```

This is my view

```py
def add_assignment(request, m_id):
template = loader.get_template('add_assignment.html')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AssignmentForm(request.POST, m_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)
        return module(request, m_id)
    else:
        print form.errors
else:
    form = AssignmentForm()

# Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
# Render the form with error messages (if any).
context = RequestContext(request, 
    {
    'form':form,
    })
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And this my URL mapping

```
url(r'^courses/(?P<m_id>\d+)/new/$', add_assignment, name='add_assignment'),
```

I'm currently getting an error because I mustn't be meant to pass values into init however I don't know how else to get the 'module_id' in.

Thanks again and I realise I might be structuring the whole thing terribly.

Comment: `Exception Value: 
name 'm_id' is not defined
Exception Location: /Users/conormurphy/Projects/FYP/assignmentcorrection/assignmentcorrection/forms.py in <module>, line 4
`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass initial parameter to django's ModelForm instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697702/how-to-pass-initial-parameter-to-djangos-modelform-instance)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is because I simply don't understand the one you linked. It only shows the class, not how to call it (and the answer the question to me seem barely similar, what's systemid?).

Comment: Also I'm not trying to pass a parameter into modelform, just into my own form.